# Prevent Auto Response rules for an auto response email

Tags: email2case, case-auto-response

Situation: We use standard out of box email-to-case and case auto-response rules. One of customer's sends a email to our system and we send an auto-response rule. They also have an automated system which sends an auto-response for all incoming emails.

Problem: Now this is causing a loop and creating about 1000 cases until Salesforce finally detects and aborts further cases from getting created.

Solution: We want to prevent sending auto-responses if we detect the incoming email is auto-generated. I know that Salesforce doesn't allow cross object reference in auto-response rules but I see EmailMessage object is available in the filter criteria. So I used EmailHeaders field from EmailMessage object and added additional filters that look for parameters that indicate in an auto generated response and prevent sending of auto-response rules from Salesforce.

[image]

Problem: Salesforce stopped sending all auto-response rule after adding this criteria. If this is a limitation is there a possible work around to break this loop?

Comment: can you use validation rule on case.suppliedemail? (assuming the customer's auto-responder has a different from address)

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is helpdesk email where our reps can send emails.

Comment: In the Email-to-Case settings, have you checked the Save Email Headers option?

Comment: Yes, that option is checked in email-to-case settings and then updated criteria in auto-response rules.

Answer (score 1):

Email-to-Case first takes the incoming email and performs a database save on the Case object. At this point in time, there is no Email Message record saved to the database.
that is the reason auto response rules are not firing
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000320092&type=1